# How can I trim all strings in an Array?

Tags: php, arrays, trim

If I have this array:

```
array("  hey  ", "bla  ", "  test");
```

and I want to trim all of them, How can I do that?

The array after the trim:

```
array("hey", "bla", "test");
```

Answer (score 494, accepted):

[array_map()](http://php.net/array_map) is what you need:

```
$result = array_map('trim', $source_array);
```

Comment: but, it will remove the associative array and return null.

Comment: @ime: it's not obvious what you mean

Comment: exp: array('a'=>' A', 'b'=>' B ', 'c'=>array(0=>'2')); it will return array('a'=>' A', 'b'=>' B ', 'c'=>null)

Comment: @ime: that's what it expected to return actually. Garbage-in garbage-out paradigm in action.

Comment: if value of any index contain another array, it returns error. how to solve it...

Comment: @ReNiShAR please ask another question. This answer was only about an array that consists of strings exclusively.

Comment: @zerkms What if i have a associative array and don't want to use loop?

Comment: @RanaGhosh not sure what your problem is. You can use `array_map` with associative arrays. https://3v4l.org/FG8vf

Answer (score 70):

[`array_map()`](http://php.net/array-map) applies a given callback to every value of an array and return the results as a new array.

```
$array = array_map('trim', $array);
```