# How can I remove the last empty space from my string inside array?

Tags: php, arrays, string, character-trimming

I am creating a array from a file:

```
$handle = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($str = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
           if (strlen($str) && $str[0] == '#') {
                    $pdate = substr($str, 1);
                    $date = rtrim($pdate);
                    $formatted = DateTime::createFromFormat('* M d H:i:s T Y',$date);
                }
                rtrim ($str, "\n");
                $exp = explode ('=', $str);
                if(count($exp) == 2){
                    $exp2 = explode('.', $exp[0]);  
                    if( count($exp2) == 2 ) {
                        if($exp2[1] == "dateTime"){
                            $s = str_replace("\\","",$exp[1]);
                            $d = strtotime($s);
                            $dateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $d);
                            $properties [$exp2[0]][$exp2[1]] = $dateTime;
                        } else {
                            $properties [$exp2[0]][$exp2[1]] = $exp[1];
                        }
                    } else {
                        $properties [$exp[0]] = $exp[1];
                    }
                } 
    }
    var_dump($properties); 
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
} 

var_dump($properties);
```

But in my result array there are always white spaces at the end of the values and I cannot get rid of them:

```
array(5) {
  ["folder"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["dateTime"]=>
    string(19) "2016-10-12 19:46:25"
    ["one"]=>
    string(47) "abc def
"
    ["two"]=>
    string(33) "ghi jk
"
    ["three"]=>
    string(150) "lm no
"
    ["four"]=>
    string(8) "pqr st
"
  }
}
```

Comment: try rtrim() of php

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I did, it is in the code. See? But nevertheless not working

Comment: You have `\r\n` characters in there, use `rtrim()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php as suggested above

Comment: You need to save the string as well. `$str = rtrim($str);`. The string isn't passed as a reference. New lines are covered by trim() as default. No need to define it manually.

Comment: You're missing to assign the result of `rtrim ($str, "\n");` should be `$str = rtrim ($str, "\n");`

Comment: @Syscall Yes, this was the mistake!

Comment: `rtrim ($str, "\n");` is working within the void

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove excess whitespace from within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703320/remove-excess-whitespace-from-within-a-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing to assign the result of `rtrim ($str, "\n");`. So your variable `$str` is not changed.

```
$str = rtrim($str, "\n");
```

Or, by default, to remove all whitespace characters (`" \t\n\r\0\x0B"`):

```
$str = rtrim($str);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can Use the rtrim() function to remove white spaces at beginning and end of your strings, but it is used one by one.
You can also reffere to the response to this post : [How can I trim all strings in an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769464/how-can-i-trim-all-strings-in-an-array?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Tha says that you can use array_map and trim as this :

`$result = array_map('rtrim', $source_array);`

Comment: He/she has new lines there also  `trim()` will not suffice

Comment: @pokeybit - Yes it is. Demo: https://3v4l.org/u1HO4

Comment: @pokeybit this it is: https://3v4l.org/PvEq4

Comment: Apologies I removed my downvote @Angelure