# How to trim the whitespace from an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, csv

I'm trying to parse a CSV file and as part of it I would like to remove leading/trailing whitespace from all of my cells. Since it's a CSV file it's formatted like a 2D array. Initially I tried:

```
foreach($csv as $row){
    foreach($row as $cell){
        $cell = trim($cell);
    }
}
```

However the result was untrimmed.

Next I tried using array_map as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762439/how-to-trim-white-spaces-of-array-values-in-php).

```
$csv = array_map('trim', $csv);
```

This gave me back an array of empty rows. So I also tried

```
foreach($csv as $row){
    $row = array_map('trim', $row);
}
```

Which like my first attempt didn't change anything.

Here's the CSV data I'm using as my input:

First Name,Last Name,Contact Method,Phone, Email
John,Doe,Email,1-XXX-XXX-XXXX, john@example.com
Jane,Doe,Phone Call,1-XXX-XXX-XXXX,jane@example.com

In particular I was trying to get my script to trim the leading space in the last cell of the first row (" Email" => "Email").

Comment: how are you creating the named keys for your data, the space is in the key and not the value so trimming the value wont do anything to the keys.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762439/how-to-trim-white-spaces-of-array-values-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not modifying the original array when you do the trim. You should get the values by reference in the `foreach` loop.

```
foreach($csv as &$row){
    foreach($row as &$cell){
        $cell = trim($cell);
    }
}
```

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop
>   precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by
>   [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference `$row` in order to make changes to the array (note the `&`):

```
foreach($csv as &$row){
    $row = array_map('trim', $row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing it like you put here,

```
" Email" => "Email"
```

you'll have to trim it from the key, can you show how you are assigning the named headers. Because I would trim it there, but using array_map('trim', $data) will remove the whitespace, I do that all day long.

Well to just clean the keys you can do,

```
 $keys = array_map( 'trim', array_keys($data) );
 $data = array_combine( $keys, $data );
```

Comment: I think his example of `" Email" => "Email"` was his way of describing the original value and the desired value he wants. Not an array structure (although it may seem like it because of his usage of `=>`)

Comment: Then why doesn't array map work, I do this 100's of times, Well I really don't but because I have a splfileobj csv reader, I should publish that by the way lol.

Comment: He forgot to pass the iterated values by reference, so he wasn't trimming the original array.

Comment: That's irrelevant for using array_map('trim', $data); as OP said they tried, there is other issues going on here, what those are is impossible to tell without more code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = [
    'parent' => [
        'child' => ' element to be trimmed '
    ]
];
array_walk_recursive($input, function (&$item) {
    if (!is_array($item)) {
        $item = trim($item);
    }
});
```