# PHP explode line break and strip blank lines and white spaces

Tags: php

I have a string called `$output` which returns a list like this

```
    Object One


    Object Two


    Object Three

    Object Four
    Object Five

    Object Six
```

I want to turn this into an array using explode like this:

```
explode("\n", $output);
```

However, there are lots of blank lines and random white spaces in the beginning. Is there a way to remove all of this so that I am left with a usable array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trim white spaces of array values in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762439/how-to-trim-white-spaces-of-array-values-in-php)

Comment: You can [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) each line produced by [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) and ignore those that are [empty strings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) after the trim. Or you can use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to use as delimiter any sequence of white spaces that includes at least one newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

**Input**

```
 $data = "        Object One


        Object Two


        Object Three

        Object Four
               Object Five

        Object Six";
```

**Solution**

```
$result = array_filter(array_map('trim',explode("\n", $data)));
echo "<pre>";   print_r($result);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Object One
    [3] => Object Two
    [6] => Object Three
    [8] => Object Four
    [9] => Object Five
    [11] => Object Six
)
```

Comment: I've used this and added array_values() in order to reindex the arrays. works well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_filter` to filter out the empty strings from the array

`array_filter(explode("\n", $output));`

For removing the whitespaces in the beginning, use `array_map`

```
$result = array_filter(explode("\n", $output));
array_map('trim', $result);
```

Comment: Should use PHP_EOL instead of "\n" for cross platform compatability and you need to store the array_map result i.e. $result = array_map( 'trim', $result);

Answer (score 1):

You can [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) each line produced by [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) and ignore those that are [empty strings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) after the trim.

Or you can use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to use as delimiter any sequence of white spaces that includes at least one newline:

```
$text = <<<E
        Object One


        Object Two


        Object Three

        Object Four
               Object Five

        Object Six
E;

var_dump(preg_split('/\s*\n(\s*\n)*\s*/', trim($text)));
```

The output is:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "Object One"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "Object Two"
  [2]=>
  string(12) "Object Three"
  [3]=>
  string(11) "Object Four"
  [4]=>
  string(11) "Object Five"
  [5]=>
  string(10) "Object Six"
}
```

The `regex`:

```
\s*            # zero or more (*) whitespaces (\s)
\n             # a newline character
(              # beginning of a group
    \s*\n      # zero or more whitespaces followed by a newline
)              # end of the group
*              # zero or more repetitions of the previous expression (the group)
\s*            # zero of more whitespaces
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_split()` to split on all newline sequences (`\R`) and include zero or more leading or trailing whitespace sequences `(\s*)`.  Pre-trim the input in case there are whitespaces at the start or end of the input string that do not neighbor a newline sequence.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aMhGt))

```
var_export(preg_split('~\s*\R\s*~', trim($string), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Object One',
  1 => 'Object Two',
  2 => 'Object Three',
  3 => 'Object Four',
  4 => 'Object Five',
  5 => 'Object Six',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 
 $data = " Object One


    Object Two


    Object Three

    Object Four
           Object Five

    Object Six";

    $data = explode("\n", $data);
    $finalArray = array();
    foreach($data as $value){
         if(!empty(trim($value))){
            $finalArray[] = trim($value);  
         }
    }

    print_r($finalArray);
```

output:

`Array ( [0] => Object One [1] => Object Two [2] => Object Three [3] => Object Four [4] => Object Five [5] => Object Six )`