# Laravel whereIn doesn't return all data

Tags: php, laravel, pluck

I have following array (created by explode method)

```
["3D Printing"," 3D Architecture"," .NET Micro Framework"]
```

when I try to match this titles to my database and get id of each of them, I only get id of first item.

```
["d21c6805-8780-4726-ba1d-12c9c3a28d0a"]
```

it supposed to return something like this

```
["d21c6805-8780-4726-ba1d-12c9c3a28d0a", "1234...", "567...]
```

`code`

```
$a = $request->input('tags');
$b = str_replace(['[',']'], null, $a);
$comingTags = explode(',',$b);

$iddss = Tag::whereIn('title', $comingTags)->pluck('id');
return response()->json($iddss);
```

**Any suggestion?**

PS: My best guess is that 2nd and 3rd item in my array have spaces and that might be causing the problem `"{SPACE IS HERE}3D Architecture"` *not sure if that's the reason.*

## Update

I've tried `$b = str_replace([',', ' '], ['',''], $a);` but all I get now is `[]`

## Update 2

By using `$b = str_replace(['[', ']', ' '], null, $a);` it does remove spaces from my strings but also removes spaces between my titles words so `3D Architecture` becomes `3DArchitecture` and by that I'm also not able to match the title with my database in `$iddss = Tag::whereIn('title', $comingTags)->pluck('id');` because my database title is `3D Architecture` and what I'm trying to match with it is `3DArchitecture`.

Any suggestion on that?

## Update 3

```
$a = $request->input('tags');
// return 
"[3D Printing, 3D Architecture, .NET Micro Framework]"
```

.

```
$b = str_replace(['[',']'], null, $a);
// return
"3D Printing, 3D Architecture, .NET Micro Framework"
```

.

```
$comingTags = explode(',',$b);
// return
["3D Printing"," 3D Architecture"," .NET Micro Framework"]
```

Comment: space can be your problem. trim those values and see if your problem is solved or not

Comment: @miladhedayatpoor how can I replace both `,` and `space` with `null`?

Comment: i think it will help you.. didnt try it muself but found on web. try this if you want to replace multiple characters at once : str_replace([  ' '  ,  ','  ], ' ', $string);

Comment: try with `$b = str_replace(['[', ']', ' '], null, $a);`

Comment: @zahidhasanemon yes that did remove the first space but it also caused another problem :) now also space between my title words are removed and there's no way it can be matched in `Tag::whereIn('title', $comingTags)->pluck('id')` :D

Comment: try `array_map('trim', $a);` for trimming whitespace from array values. see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5762453/1908609

Comment: @SidneyGijzen you mean I should remove `str_replace(['[',']', ' '], null, $a)` and replace it with your suggestion?

Comment: what does your `$a` like? `'["3D Printing"," 3D Architecture"," .NET Micro Framework"]'` an string? when you use `str_replace(['[',']'], null, $a);` what does the value look like? `""3D Printing"," 3D Architecture"," .NET Micro Framework""`? like this??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon no my `$a` is like `[3D Printing,3D Architecture,.NET Micro Framework]` and `$b` makes it like `["3D Printing"," 3D Architecture"," .NET Micro Framework"]`

Comment: according to the code `$b` result should not have the `[` and `]`. are you sure?

Comment: @mafortis can you make sure `$a` is an array or string when you are receiving it??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon that was what I tried to do with `$b` make array of `$a` somehow it still read it as string and not array.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon update my question

Comment: your initial `$a` and update 3 `$a` is different. which one is correct??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon update 3 is. and I think it's fixed now see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67175038/laravel-wherein-doesnt-return-all-data#comment118739974_67175920

Comment: yeah you have added the wrong info first. glad the problem resolves.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon yes, my apology. Thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of whitespace you can do
`array_map('trim', $a);` ([credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5762453/1908609))

[whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) expects an array, so this should work

```php
$a = $request->input('tags');
$b = str_replace(['[',']'], null, $a);
$comingTags = array_map('trim', explode(',', $b));

$iddss = Tag::whereIn('title', $comingTags)->pluck('id');

return response()->json($iddss);
```

Comment: it says `array_map(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, string given`

Comment: still giving same error, somehow it doesn't recognize `$b` as of array.

Comment: can you update your question with the exact values of $a and $b?

Comment: this does the job :D `$a = $request->input('tags');
        $b = str_replace(['[',']'], null, $a);
        $comingTags = explode(',',$b);
        $comingTags2 = array_map('trim', $comingTags);
        $iddss = Tag::whereIn('title', $comingTags2)->pluck('id');
        return response()->json($iddss);`

Comment: I am gonna accept your answer because the `trim` did the trick but please update your answer with my provided solution which is working code. Thanks a lot.